# Angular tutorial (tour of heroes) doesn't displays correct alignment on heroes' list

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm doing Angular's tour of heroes tutorial. Unfortunately, when I'm going to load the list of heroes it displays like this:
[image]

And this is strange, because the list isn't aligned even if my css/html/ts from the tutorial seems right! I've seen more times every single step and the code reported by the example. Below the full component that "controls" the list.

heroes.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from '../hero';
import {HEROES} from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedHero: Hero;
  heroes = HEROES;

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

heroes.component.css

```
/* HeroesComponent's private CSS styles */
.selected {
  background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
  color: white;
}
.heroes {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15em;
}
.heroes li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  height: 1.6em;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.heroes li.selected:hover {
  background-color: #BBD8DC !important;
  color: white;
}
.heroes li:hover {
  color: #607D8B;
  background-color: #DDD;
  left: .1em;
}
.heroes .text {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
.heroes .badge {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: -1px;
  top: -4px;
  height: 1.8em;
  margin-right: .8em;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
```

heroes.component.html

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
      (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="selectedHero">

  <h2>{{ selectedHero.name | uppercase }} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name">
    </label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've resolved, and because it is a bit subtle error I want to share it here.

When you create a new angular project from the cli, in app.component.html you obtain:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
      Welcome to {{ title }}!
    </h1>
    [...]
</div>
[...]
```

From the tutorial it asks to delete the template and substitute with `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`. The part that is unclear (at least for me, could be for others) is that you must substitute **all** the template. If you only delete `<h1>` and the other tag within the div, you obtain

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
```

and then

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <app-heroes></app-heroes>
</div>
```

that leads to the error above.

The correct version of app.component.html is simply:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<app-heroes></app-heroes>
```

Answer (score -1):

That is definately the solution, remove that inline style (`style="text-align:center"`) and the style sheet should have it align perfectly for you.